# How can I detect when the user has pressed the power off button?

Tags: c++, c, linux, power-management

I have an arcade cocktail cabinet (no keyboard, just a joystick and buttons) running Ubuntu 12.4.1, when the power button is pressed a popup appears and the system shuts down fine, but when my full-screen game launcher menu application is running then pressing the button has no effect. I would like to trap the event when the button is pressed so my app can trigger the system shutdown. My menu app is written in c++ and is using SDL. Any ideas on how I can trap the power off button press event?

Thanks to those that responded, here is the actual code I used to get it to work:

**Class members:**

```
int m_acpidsock;
sockaddr_un m_acpidsockaddr;
```

**Setup code:**

```
/* Connect to acpid socket */
m_acpidsock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(m_acpidsock>=0)
{
    m_acpidsockaddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(m_acpidsockaddr.sun_path,"/var/run/acpid.socket");
    if(connect(m_acpidsock, (struct sockaddr *)&m_acpidsockaddr, 108)<0)
    {
        /* can't connect */
        close(m_acpidsock);
        m_acpidsock=-1;
    }
}
```

**Update code:**

```
/* check for any power events */
if(m_acpidsock)
{
    char buf[1024];
    int s=recv(m_acpidsock, buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_DONTWAIT);

    if(s>0)
    {
        buf[s]=0;
        printf("ACPID:%s\n\n",buf);
        if(!strncmp(buf,"button/power",12))
        {
            setShutdown();
            system("shutdown -P now");
        }
    }
}
```

**Close socket code:**

```
if(m_acpidsock>=0)
{
    close(m_acpidsock);
    m_acpidsock=-1;
}
```

Lastly, I needed to allow non-root users to shutdown and that worked using this line:

```
sudo chmod u+s /sbin/shutdown
```

Comment: No, but that sounds pretty cool!

Comment: What is that number 108 in the connect() call?  Shouldn't it be sizeof(m_acpidsockaddr) instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just start a thread to read from `/proc/events/acpi`, and decode the messages there.

But how about using `acpid` to do that? You'd listen to the `/var/run/acpid.socket`, and when a message you care about comes in, do what you have do to.

See:
http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man8/acpid.8.php

I hope this is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [acpid](http://linux.die.net/man/8/acpid), I think you could change one of the scripts in `/etc/acpi/` specifically `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` to add custom commands. You could also try reading `/proc/acpi/event` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Things like pressing the power button trigger ACPI events which acpid fires off a script in response to as configured in /etc/acpi/events. In this case you want /etc/acpi/powerbtn, which looks something like this:

```
event=button[ /]power
action=/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
```

You can either customize /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh, or point it at another script of your choosing.